# enable overflown data visible outside the container

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, overflow

The following is the container

```
<div key={issue.issueId} className="issue-container" style={{ paddingBottom: "0.5rem" }}>
            <button
              className="collapsible-button btn btn-info" style={{ backgroundColor: "gray" }}
              onClick={() => toggleIssueContent(issue.issueId)}
            >
              {openIssues[issue.issueId] ? '▲' : '▼'} {/* Arrow button */}
              <span style={{ paddingLeft: "1rem" }}>{issue.issueWith}</span>
            </button>
            {/* Render issue details if it's selected */}
            {openIssues[issue.issueId] && (
              <div className="collapsible-content" style={{ backgroundColor: "#CAC8C8" }}>
                <p>User id: {issue.userId}</p>
                <p>Issue id : {issue.issueId}</p>
                <p>Issue Description: {issue.issueDescription}</p>
                <Buttons uniqueId={issue.issueId + issue.username} />
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
```

The `Buttons` is the following code

```
<div className="btn-group float-right" role="group" aria-label="Button group">
            <div className={`dropdown ${isOpen ? 'show' : ''}`}>
                <button className="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" id={`forwardDropdown-${uniqueId}`} aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded={isOpen ? 'true' : 'false'} onClick={toggleDropdown}>
                    Forward
                </button>
                <div className={`dropdown-menu ${isOpen ? 'show' : ''}`} aria-labelledby={`forwardDropdown-${uniqueId}`}>
                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type='button' className="btn btn-danger">Discard</button>
        </div>
```

**What I want is the dropdown-menu's content to be shown which is overflowing outside the issue-container**
The following is the styles for the `issue-container`

```
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    --blue: #007bff;
    --indigo: #6610f2;
    --purple: #6f42c1;
    --pink: #e83e8c;
    --red: #dc3545;
    --orange: #fd7e14;
    --yellow: #ffc107;
    --green: #28a745;
    --teal: #20c997;
    --cyan: #17a2b8;
    --white: #fff;
    --gray: #6c757d;
    --gray-dark: #343a40;
    --primary: #007bff;
    --secondary: #6c757d;
    --success: #28a745;
    --info: #17a2b8;
    --warning: #ffc107;
    --danger: #dc3545;
    --light: #f8f9fa;
    --dark: #343a40;
    --breakpoint-xs: 0;
    --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
    --breakpoint-md: 768px;
    --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
    --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
    --font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;
    --fa-font-brands: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Brands";
    --fa-font-regular: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
    --fa-font-solid: normal 900 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
```

The following are the styles for the `btn-group`

```
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    --blue: #007bff;
    --indigo: #6610f2;
    --purple: #6f42c1;
    --pink: #e83e8c;
    --red: #dc3545;
    --orange: #fd7e14;
    --yellow: #ffc107;
    --green: #28a745;
    --teal: #20c997;
    --cyan: #17a2b8;
    --white: #fff;
    --gray: #6c757d;
    --gray-dark: #343a40;
    --primary: #007bff;
    --secondary: #6c757d;
    --success: #28a745;
    --info: #17a2b8;
    --warning: #ffc107;
    --danger: #dc3545;
    --light: #f8f9fa;
    --dark: #343a40;
    --breakpoint-xs: 0;
    --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
    --breakpoint-md: 768px;
    --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
    --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
    --font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;
    --fa-font-brands: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Brands";
    --fa-font-regular: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
    --fa-font-solid: normal 900 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right!important;
```

The following are the styles for the `forward dropdown btn`

```
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    --blue: #007bff;
    --indigo: #6610f2;
    --purple: #6f42c1;
    --pink: #e83e8c;
    --red: #dc3545;
    --orange: #fd7e14;
    --yellow: #ffc107;
    --green: #28a745;
    --teal: #20c997;
    --cyan: #17a2b8;
    --white: #fff;
    --gray: #6c757d;
    --gray-dark: #343a40;
    --primary: #007bff;
    --secondary: #6c757d;
    --success: #28a745;
    --info: #17a2b8;
    --warning: #ffc107;
    --danger: #dc3545;
    --light: #f8f9fa;
    --dark: #343a40;
    --breakpoint-xs: 0;
    --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
    --breakpoint-md: 768px;
    --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
    --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
    --font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;
    --fa-font-brands: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Brands";
    --fa-font-regular: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
    --fa-font-solid: normal 900 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    overflow: visible;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #28a745;
    border-color: #28a745;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
```

*If you want any more styles to check for the behavior, please free to request them*

The following is the container

```
<div key={issue.issueId} className="issue-container" style={{ paddingBottom: "0.5rem" }}>
            <button
              className="collapsible-button btn btn-info" style={{ backgroundColor: "gray" }}
              onClick={() => toggleIssueContent(issue.issueId)}
            >
              {openIssues[issue.issueId] ? '▲' : '▼'} {/* Arrow button */}
              <span style={{ paddingLeft: "1rem" }}>{issue.issueWith}</span>
            </button>
            {/* Render issue details if it's selected */}
            {openIssues[issue.issueId] && (
              <div className="collapsible-content" style={{ backgroundColor: "#CAC8C8" }}>
                <p>User id: {issue.userId}</p>
                <p>Issue id : {issue.issueId}</p>
                <p>Issue Description: {issue.issueDescription}</p>
                <Buttons uniqueId={issue.issueId + issue.username} />
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
```

The `Buttons` is the following code

```
<div className="btn-group float-right" role="group" aria-label="Button group">
            <div className={`dropdown ${isOpen ? 'show' : ''}`}>
                <button className="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" id={`forwardDropdown-${uniqueId}`} aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded={isOpen ? 'true' : 'false'} onClick={toggleDropdown}>
                    Forward
                </button>
                <div className={`dropdown-menu ${isOpen ? 'show' : ''}`} aria-labelledby={`forwardDropdown-${uniqueId}`}>
                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type='button' className="btn btn-danger">Discard</button>
        </div>
```

**What I want is the dropdown-menu's content to be shown which is overflowing outside the issue-container**
The following is the styles for the `issue-container`

```
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    --blue: #007bff;
    --indigo: #6610f2;
    --purple: #6f42c1;
    --pink: #e83e8c;
    --red: #dc3545;
    --orange: #fd7e14;
    --yellow: #ffc107;
    --green: #28a745;
    --teal: #20c997;
    --cyan: #17a2b8;
    --white: #fff;
    --gray: #6c757d;
    --gray-dark: #343a40;
    --primary: #007bff;
    --secondary: #6c757d;
    --success: #28a745;
    --info: #17a2b8;
    --warning: #ffc107;
    --danger: #dc3545;
    --light: #f8f9fa;
    --dark: #343a40;
    --breakpoint-xs: 0;
    --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
    --breakpoint-md: 768px;
    --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
    --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
    --font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;
    --fa-font-brands: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Brands";
    --fa-font-regular: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
    --fa-font-solid: normal 900 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
```

The following are the styles for the `btn-group`

```
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    --blue: #007bff;
    --indigo: #6610f2;
    --purple: #6f42c1;
    --pink: #e83e8c;
    --red: #dc3545;
    --orange: #fd7e14;
    --yellow: #ffc107;
    --green: #28a745;
    --teal: #20c997;
    --cyan: #17a2b8;
    --white: #fff;
    --gray: #6c757d;
    --gray-dark: #343a40;
    --primary: #007bff;
    --secondary: #6c757d;
    --success: #28a745;
    --info: #17a2b8;
    --warning: #ffc107;
    --danger: #dc3545;
    --light: #f8f9fa;
    --dark: #343a40;
    --breakpoint-xs: 0;
    --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
    --breakpoint-md: 768px;
    --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
    --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
    --font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;
    --fa-font-brands: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Brands";
    --fa-font-regular: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
    --fa-font-solid: normal 900 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right!important;
```

The following are the styles for the `forward dropdown btn`

```
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    --blue: #007bff;
    --indigo: #6610f2;
    --purple: #6f42c1;
    --pink: #e83e8c;
    --red: #dc3545;
    --orange: #fd7e14;
    --yellow: #ffc107;
    --green: #28a745;
    --teal: #20c997;
    --cyan: #17a2b8;
    --white: #fff;
    --gray: #6c757d;
    --gray-dark: #343a40;
    --primary: #007bff;
    --secondary: #6c757d;
    --success: #28a745;
    --info: #17a2b8;
    --warning: #ffc107;
    --danger: #dc3545;
    --light: #f8f9fa;
    --dark: #343a40;
    --breakpoint-xs: 0;
    --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
    --breakpoint-md: 768px;
    --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
    --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
    --font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;
    --fa-font-brands: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Brands";
    --fa-font-regular: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
    --fa-font-solid: normal 900 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    overflow: visible;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #28a745;
    border-color: #28a745;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
```

*If you want any more styles to check for the behavior, please free to request them*